# How to know the directory containing the java run time in Windows XP?

Tags: java, windows

There are a lot of jdk and jre in my `program files`. I want to know the directory which contains the java runtime of my Windows XP system. How to achieve that ?

Comment: May be by `echo %JAVA_HOME%` or `echo %JRE_HOME%` in cmd.

Comment: If you want to know which one runs when you write `java` in the command like, type `PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, figuring it out via environment variables (JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME) may not be sufficient enough. The best under Windows is to check Java registry below:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
```

Both registry paths contain `CurrentVersion` key that denotes the latest current version installed

Use it to browse further down the target registry to find `JavaHome` as follows:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\{CurrentVersion}\JavaHome
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.getProperties()` or `System.getProperty(key)` method.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
```

Comment: To add, `java.home` system property gets its value from Java Windows registry rather than from system environment variables